# Check if user is logged in else login page

Tags: admin, wp-login-form

I like to secure a certain page for admins. How do I check if a user is logged (and is admin)? Of their not logged in, I want to show the login module.

Comment: What do you mean by page: is this a wordpress page or any url?

Comment: This doesnt make complete sense.  If the user is logged in but not an admin, what happens?

Comment: @user42826 - I would assume that the user can't access the page. In my mind, that would be an error message (indicating too low of a role) or just directing somewhere else (although I'm personally not a fan of blind redirects as that is a poor user experience IMO).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(!current_user_can('administrator')) {
    wp_redirect( wp_login_url() );
}
```

This will redirect non-admins to login URL. Of course, logged in non-admins will be a bit confused. You'll want to run this before `get_header()`

Comment: While this does work, passing a role name (such as 'administrator') is an incorrect use of the current_user_can() function and results can be inconsistent. You should pass a capability associated with the role rather than the role name (see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can#Notes ).

Comment: I agree. I'm fond of `current_user_can( 'manage_options' )` for this particular check, myself.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can set a page as PRIVATE and give a password for it. You get this option when you "Quick Edit" a page.